# Get notified when iPad enters in split-screen multitasking mode

Tags: ios, split-screen-multitasking

I have a `viewcontroller` and I need to know when the `iPad` enters in **split screen multitasking** mode in order to resize the elements of my view accordingly.

What is the `delegate` method fired when this happens ?

Comment: Did you try to override viewWillTransitionToSize(size:, withTransitionCoordinator:) ?

Comment: Yep I found that method 1 minute after posting, gonna answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the method invoked when entering split-view screen

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

Comment: FYI - this is called at other times too, not just when entering split screen mode.